# port out of range:-1 for Web Socket API via WSO2 API Manager

Tags: websocket, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to run a web-socket service via a WSO2 API Manager (as an API Gateway).  I had a working proof-of-concept with the gateway running against a service on my laptop (gateway is on a server, but i ran the service in Eclipse to test it).  Now I am trying to get it working against a service running on another server.  If I call the URL that is configured as the endpoint in the API Definition in the gateway then it works.  if i run via the gateway then it doesn't.  The wso2carbon.log shows:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,260] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:224)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketConnectionFactory.cacheNewConnection(WebsocketConnectionFactory.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketConnectionFactory.getChannelHandler(WebsocketConnectionFactory.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketTransportSender.sendMessage(WebsocketTransportSender.java:106)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:592)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:548)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:382)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:121)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:1005)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.injectToSequence(InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.java:469)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.handleHandshake(InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.java:182)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.channelRead(InboundWebsocketSourceHandler.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.WebsocketInboundHandler.channelRead(WebsocketInboundHandler.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:147)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:147)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,267]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,267]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address ws://redacted.example.com/notifications/v1 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,267]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address ws://redacted.example.com/notifications/v1 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Jul 02 16:01:25 EEST 2019 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,267]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-02 16:00:55,345]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 303001, ERROR_MESSAGE = Currently , Address endpoint : [ Name : AnonymousEndpoint ] [ State : SUSPENDED ] {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Running v 2.1 of WSO2 API Manager (yes, we are actively planning an upgrade but I need to get it working on the current version if possible).  Unfortunately I am having problems repeating my initial PoC against my machine too.  I think it's something in the gateway (although I am not aware of having changed anything).  However, my IT department has changed which firewall we have on our local machines in the meantime so I can't rule that out...

Answer (score 0):

When using wss endpoint, we were able to observe some errors and we were able to get rid of the errors with the following approach.

Please include the following parameter in the SecureWebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml file which resides in the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/inbound-endpoints directory.

```
<parameter name="wss.ssl.protocols">TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter>
```

Also, please remove the following parameters from the same SecureWebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml file if the following parameters(wss.ssl.trust.store.file and wss.ssl.trust.store.pass) exist in the file.

```
<parameter name="wss.ssl.trust.store.file">repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</parameter>
<parameter name="wss.ssl.trust.store.pass">wso2carbon</parameter>
```

Please use the following sample web socket client to try out and run the WSS client. Please change the variable carbonKeyStoreLocation to point to <API-M_HOME>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks. Note that port for the WSS API is 8099.
You can download the WSS client in the following WSO2 official documentation under the **WSS Support** section. (In the second step.)[1]  Further please change the access token, web socket endpoint and the carbonKeyStoreLocation with your one to try out the scenario.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+a+WebSocket+API

When using ws endpoint, you do not need to configure the carbonKeyStoreLocation. Only you need to include the correct access token and correct ws endpoint. You can get the WS client in the same above documentation.[1]